# Declare Boost ptime globally

Tags: c++, boost, posix

I am attmepting to declare boost ptime at the global level. However I am encountering the following issue:

Before the main function I declare:

```
static boost::posix_time::ptime start_time;
```

Then inside the main function I initialize:

```
boost::posix_time::ptime start_time(boost::posix_time::microsec_clock::universal_time());
```

Then in a function outside the main function, I tried to convert to a string and print and I get "not-a-date-time";

Either the global variable is not being initialized or there is a scope problem?
Thank you for your help.

Comment: is your other function in a different cpp file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You define a *local* variable inside the `main` function, one that shadows the global variable but has nothing to do with the global variable.

You should not define the variable in the `main` function, only assign to it:

```
start_time = boost::posix_time::microsec_clock::universal_time();
```

Answer (score 1):

```
boost::posix_time::ptime start_time(boost::posix_time::microsec_clock::universal_time());
```

Is not going to initialize `start_time` from the global scope.  This is going to create a new variable named `start_time` that is scoped to `main` and hides the global `start_time`.  When you try to use the global `start_time` in another function you get a `not-a-date-time` error because `start_times` was never initialized with an actual date.

You either need to do the initialization in the global space, do an assignment in main, or get rid of the global variable, declare it in main, and pass it by reference to the functions that need it.  Personally I would go with the last option if possible as globals make the code harder to reason about.